# Move a circle along the circumference of another circle

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, circles

I am trying to make a simple program to just move a circle around another circle.

The circle starts from the right side of the bigger circle and moves upwards.

See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HFpm.jpg

I tried doing that by just moving it 1 pixel at a time, so `circle.move(-x, -y)` where $x = y = 1$. That didn't work because the circle was doing a linear movement, while I wanted it to follow the curvature of the main circle.

I am using Python and the `graphics.py` library to do the animation.
This is the linear movement I was talking about. This is 90 loops because the secondary circle is moving 90 degrees.

See animation: https://gfycat.com/anothergrippingheifer

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from graphics import *


def main():
    width = 500
    height = 500
    win = GraphWin("Main", width, height, autoflush=False)
    win.setBackground(color_rgb(255, 255, 255))

    main_rad = 100
    main_circle = Circle(Point(width//2, height//2), main_rad)
    main_circle.setFill(color_rgb(255, 0, 0))
    main_circle.setWidth(3)
    main_circle.draw(win)

    sec_rad = main_rad // 2
    sec_circleX = main_circle.getCenter().getX() + main_rad + sec_rad
    sec_circleY = main_circle.getCenter().getY()
    sec_circle = Circle(Point(sec_circleX, sec_circleY), sec_rad)
    sec_circle.setFill(color_rgb(80, 135, 230))
    sec_circle.setWidth(3)
    sec_circle.draw(win)

    x = 1
    y = 1
    for i in range(90):
        sec_circle.move(-x, -y)  # Moves the center of the circle by the given amount
        update(30)

    win.getMouse()  # Just to view the window

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I don't know how to approach this problem and some answers that I saw where a bit complicated, or not well explained.
I don't know what to tag this because I don't have a lot of math knowledge.

Comment: Move the center of the moving circle by increasing $t$ in $(x,y)=(a\cdot\cos t,a\cdot\sin t)$ where $a$ is the sum of radii of the circles where the center of the not moving circle is $(0,0)$.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin How would I calculate the radii to position the circle? The center of the stable circle is the center of the window which is (250,250).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you alter the last half of the program to look something like this (I have **not** tested this code; it's written off the top of my head):

```
    sec_rad = main_rad // 2
    big_rad = main_rad + sec_rad
   
    sec_circle = Circle(Point(0,0), 0)
    for i in range(90):
        sec_circle.undraw(win)
        c = cos(i * 3.14159/180)
        s = sin(i * 3.14159/180)

        sec_circleX = main_circle.getCenter().getX() + big_rad * c
        sec_circleY = main_circle.getCenter().getY() + big_rad * s
        sec_circle.setFill(color_rgb(80, 135, 230))
        sec_circle.setWidth(3) 
        sec_circle.draw(win)
        update(30)
```

NB: the line `sec_circle.setWidth(3)` seems wrong to me; I'd think it would be `sec_circle.setWidth(sec_rad * 2)`, since the width of a circle is twice its radius, but I may be misunderstanding your intent here.

There are three main ideas here.

1. Repeatedly "moving" objects amounts to computing sums, and in most programming languages, $\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} \ne 1$, so it's better to just approximately compute the value you want once and then throw it away, rather than reusing both it, and the error it entails
2. If you want the object to move at a constant speed, the angle from the center of the big circle to the center of the small circle needs to grow at a constant rate. (A lot of people would use the name `theta` or `t` where you've used `i` for this very reason --- the angle you're using is represented by `i`.
3. To avoid the problem of accumulating errors, you need to destroy and recreate your circle-object's existence in the window, because this library's design is perhaps not so great(*). So we're using "undraw" and then "draw" within the loop. That's ugly, but it's what needs to be done. To make it work, `sec_circle` has to be defined before we enter the loop, so we make a bogus circle just before the loop simply so that when we call "undraw", we don't get an error. Sigh.

(*) When I say that the design is "not so great," I mean "as a graphics library" not "as a teaching tool." It may actually serve the author well as a teaching tool, which seems to be [where it arose](https://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics/graphics.pdf). You may think I'm talking through my hat about whether it's a good library or not, and I'm sure smart people would be happy to debate me. But I am an author of one of the standard computer graphics [texts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Graphics:_Principles_and_Practice), and have been doing computer graphics of one kind or another since about 1975. Nearly a half-century of experience has taught me a lot of lessons. Take my opinion for what it's worth.

Comment: I didn't explain that part. `sec_circle.setWidth(3)` only makes the circumference of the circle a bit thicker. No math is involved. Just the width of the line. Also this is the first library I used and this is not a program i will be using, it's just so I can visualize cycloids and this is the beginning of that. This is the result of your code: https://gfycat.com/requiredgoodnaturedgemsbuck . It does not revolve around the circle 90 degrees. Any help?

Comment: Oops. I assumed that the sine and cosine took degrees rather than radians because... brain lapse. I've edited to fix that now.

Comment: As for "setWidth", I read the documentation as saying that it set the width of the bounding-box to that size, but it clearly says "the outline". The problem is that "the outline" isn't really a standard term. What's the outline of a  piece of text? Or of a textured square? Anyhow, glad that part isn't a problem.

Comment: It is worded that way because the same method is used for other shapes, like lines, rectangles, ovals and others. The outline of the circle is the curve that covers its circumference. If for exampleyou set that line to $0$ then the is no black line falling on the circle's circumference. It seems to work now. Do you have any sources I can read up on this subject?

Comment: This is the final animation: https://gfycat.com/velvetyalienateddassie. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Glad to have been of service. As for sources on how to make graphics...well, there's this textbook. :) Seriously, the web is a wonderful place, and I'm sure that there's a tutorial out there somewhere that's tuned to your level of mathematics, which is one of the main match-ups you want to make.

Comment: I'll look into it a bit more then. Thanks for you help again.